# Getting natbib to follow IEEE numeric citation format

Tags: citing, natbib, ieeetran

I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a better way to tweak `natbib` to generate numeric references that follow IEEE's [citation reference guide](http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf) and [style manual](http://www.ieee.org/portal/cms_docs_iportals/iportals/publications/authors/transjnl/stylemanual.pdf). Specifically, IEEE wants each of a group of citations in separate brackets (like this: **[1], [2]**), but `natbib` seems to insist on grouping them (like so: **[1, 2]**).

The `cite` package handles this correctly, and I know the `natbib` IEEE templates are "not recommended" for IEEE submission, but I like being able to pull the name of the author(s) into the text sometimes, which `natbib` lets me do with `\citet`. Using `natbib` also lets me switch to author-year citations, if I end up having to change publications, without going through and changing every citation, which is also nice.

I can get close in `natbib` by setting the separator punctuation to `], [` (using `\bibpunct`), but `natbib` appears to add a hard-coded space after the separator (looks like this: **[1], [ 2]** (note the space in front of the 2; it looks more prominent in my typeset copy)). My solution at this point is to override one of the macros in `natbib.sty` in my own document, to remove the space (which can be put onto the end of the separator string if it's needed):

```
\makeatletter
\def\NAT@def@citea{\def\@citea{\NAT@separator}}% removed \NAT@space
\makeatother
```

Is there a more elegant and robust solution, with either `cite` or `natbib`? Or should I start looking into `biblatex` (which I've just found out about) for future work?

Comment: Why not just use `\cite{author1}, \cite{author2}` (a seperate `\cite` for each reference) instead of `\cite{author1, author2}`?

Comment: I think your solution can't be improved very much. However I also recommend `biblatex`.

Comment: @Werner, if you mean using two separate `\citep` entries, that's an okay workaround to get the formatting I need, but it would break the formatting if I switched to another citation format. The regular `cite` package already does the formatting correctly (so I wouldn't need two separate `\cite`s--your second example works correctly), but it doesn't support inlining author names. `natbib` does, but gets the formatting slightly wrong. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: Thanks, @Marco. I'll check out `biblatex` when I have the time, and use my workaround for now.

Comment: Side-issue: I often publish in IEEE related journals and conferences and they simply don't mind since seperate brackets look (I think) awful. So I wouldn't mind that much.

Comment: @percusse: Thanks for sharing your experience. I sort of thought as much, since I've seen it both ways in papers--especially in conference proceedings. However, the **[1, 2]** format is ambiguous when you, say, reference a page number: **[1, p.53]**. Sure, it's clear enough, but I prefer the separate brackets for consistency.

Comment: I use nothing more than `\documentclass[final]{IEEEtran}\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}` and in the end of the document `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` before my bib file declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution can't be improved very well. I recommend switching to `biblatex`.

However @Werner suggested a separate `\cite` command for each reference.

To avoid this you can use something like this:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\Origcite}{\cite}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\cite[1]{%
 \@for \i:={#1}\do{%
      \Origcite{#1}%
      }%
}
```

Note that with this way you lose the optional argument of `\cite`.

Comment: Ah! Nice idea, @Marco! Is it necessary to lose the optional argument, though? I do use it sometimes, but it would only be in the case where there is a single citation, I think. (Unlikely you'd reference the same page in both sources. Which kind of points to a flaw in the design of the `\cite` command -- that single and multiple citations behave differently. Maybe another reason to think about switching.)

Comment: @big_m: Of course you can modify and expand the code. But for a small workaround it's to much ;-)