# IEEEtran and natbib: forbid line break after [ in citation

Tags: natbib, ieeetran

I am using a series of small hacks to use `IEEEtran` with `natbib` (I like `\citeauthor` and the like). In an eleven-page document, this produces identical-looking pdf output with and without `\ifhack`, with one exception: line breaks after "[".

Without the hack, I get

```
A [1],
[2]
```

With the hack, I get

```
A [1], [
2
```

What can I do to solve this? This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\newif\ifhack
\hacktrue
\ifhack
    \let\theoldbibliography\thebibliography
    \usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
    \let\thebibliography\theoldbibliography

    \makeatletter

    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47317/
    \def\NAT@def@citea{\def\@citea{\NAT@separator}}% removed \NAT@space

    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \patchcmd{\NAT@citexnum}{--}{]--[}{}{}

    \makeatother

    \bibpunct{[}{]}{], [}{n}{}{,}
\else
    \usepackage{cite}

    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229126/
    \AtBeginDocument{\let\normalsfcodes\frenchspacing}
\fi

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a}
@article{b}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\parbox{1.2cm}{A \cite{a,b}}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I should add that there are other differences when a paragraph is started with `\cite{...}`. In these case, indentation is off (different a paragraph not starting with in `\cite{...}`) in `IEEEtran`, while it is OK in my hacked version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the call to `\bibpunct` by this fixed it for me:

```
\def\NAT@sep{], [}  
\def\NAT@separator{\NAT@sep}% removed \NAT@penalty
```